# Is there a short way in PHP to express $item->foo() for callback?

Tags: php

You can write something like `array_map($array, [$object, 'method']);` to call a method for every member of an array.

If, on the other hand, you have a list of objects you need to write `array_map($array, function ($item) { return $item->method();});` which is anything but easy to read. Is there some way to shorten this?

Comment: The key word being '*possible*', no need to get so worked up.

Comment: Didn't you mean `array_walk`? In `array_map`, the $array is the second argument, callback is the first..

Comment: To be fair, you are comparing apples to oranges. In the first example you are referencing a function by its name and you don't show the actual function code. If you'd apply the same to the second example, it would be even shorter than the first one. Actually I don't even see a difference between `every member of an array` and `list of objects` - it is the same, only the callback looks slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally prefer a regular loop in this situation. Short and easy to read:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $item->method();
}
```

If you want to stick with `array_map()`, a lambda function makes it more readable in my opinion (but not shorter):

```
$func = function($item) {
    return $item->method();
};

$array = array_map($func, $array);
```

Comment: I agree - if readability is the goal here then a simple foreach would be my solution